# CMake `target_link_libraries` with PRIVATE shared libraries in non-standard locations

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a CMake file along the following lines:

```
add_library(foo SHARED foo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo
  PRIVATE
  bar::bar
)
```

In this case `bar::bar` is some imported shared library at a non-default system location, that is only used within the implementation of `foo`.

`foo` builds and links correctly. I have a problem when using `foo` as a dependency for other libraries. For example:

```
add_library(baz SHARED baz.cpp)
target_link_libraries(baz
  PRIVATE
  foo
)
```

This now results in linker errors, since the linker can not find `libbar.so` which is linked against `libfoo.so`. It can be solved by making `bar` a `PUBLIC` dependency of `foo`, but I am worried this is not the right solution (as mentioned, `bar` is only used for the implementation of `foo`).

What would be a good solution in this case? I think using `target_link_directories` or `link_directories` to add the location of `bar` might work, but apparently usage of those functions is frowned upon, and so this leads me to believe there might be a better solution to this problem?

**Update**: I figured out eventually that by default, CMake has no problem with a small reproducible case as explained above. CMake will add the location of `bar` as an *rpath* to the `foo` library, ensuring that the linker will find it when it has to link `baz` using `foo`.

In our case, we have a custom `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH` together with the option `CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH` enabled. This disables the default CMake behavior, causing linking issues.

I ended up fixing this by setting a custom `-rpath-link` flag for the linker, so that it can find the libraries in non-standard locations, only during build time. This can be done as follows for example:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-rpath-link=${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/lib")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-rpath-link=${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/lib")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-rpath-link=${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/lib")
```

Comment: Can we see some more code? foo.cpp and baz.cpp, any headers they may include, etc.

Comment: @Pesho_T, I'll work on putting some code together that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Pesho_T, I found that by making a small reproducible example, CMake actually does the right thing! It automatically adds an rpath to the `foo` library of the non-standard location of `bar`. I was surprised to see that. So now I have to figure out why that does not happen in our main project. Thank you for putting me on the right track. I'll post some more details once I have figured out exactly what is going on.