CMake Library not linking correctly when used by other projects
I'm a CMake and C++ beginner and am trying to create an C++ based MQTT client library. My library depends on two other libraries, PahoMqttCpp::paho-mqtpp3 and nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json.
Out of these two I want the json library to be PUBLIC-linked since json-objects are part of the clients API. On the other hand, I don't want users of the project to access or modify the internal PahoMqttCpp client I am using and therefore I want to link it privately (if I understand PUBLIC and PRIVATE linking correctly).
This is a rough recreation of my CMakeLists.txt:
# ...Project and library initialization

find_package(PahoMqttCpp REQUIRED)
find_package(nlohmann_json REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(MQTTClient
        PRIVATE PahoMqttCpp::paho-mqttpp3
        PUBLIC nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)

install(TARGETS MQTTClient
        EXPORT MQTTClientTargets
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
        INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
)

install(EXPORT MQTTClientTargets
        FILE MQTTClientTargets.cmake
        NAMESPACE MQTTClient::
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/MQTTClient
)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
configure_package_config_file(
        cmake/MQTTClientConfig.cmake.in
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/WaraPSClientConfig.cmake
        INSTALL_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/WaraPSClient
)

write_basic_package_version_file(
        MQTTClientConfigVersion.cmake
        VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
        COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion
)

install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MQTTClientConfig.cmake
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MQTTClientConfigVersion.cmake
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/MQTTClient
)

Together with a very rudimentary MQTTClientConfig.cmake.in file. This builds and links correctly and I am able to install the library using cmake, however, when I try to use this in another project with a CMakeLists.txt that looks like this:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7...3.29)

project(Test)

add_executable(Test src/main.cc)

find_package(MQTTClient)
target_link_libraries(Test MQTTClient)

I get the following error when trying to link the executable:
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libMQTTClient.so: undefined reference to `mqtt::properties::properties()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test.dir/build.make:97: Test] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/Test.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this doesn't work, I've been stuck with this error for the major part of two days and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I guess that your PahoMqttCpp::paho-mqttpp3 are also shared libraries, then your libMQTTClient.so has unresolved dependency to whateverItsCalled.so that defines properties() symbol. What if you link with static version of PahoMqttCpp::paho-mqttpp3? I cannot think of an example where privately linking shared libraries would work.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61479487/cmake-target-link-libraries-with-private-shared-libraries-in-non-standard-loca Similar topic, but without answers.

https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2016-May/063400.html even CMake docs mention "If other code links directly to A, then it also will have encoded into it a dependency on A. It will not, however, have a dependency on B unless A links in B as PUBLIC or INTERFACE." - that's about SHARED. And then there is a section about STATIC where PRIVATE linking might be usefull.

I've tried linking it publically as well and get the same error. PahoMqttCpp::paho-mqttpp3 depends on eclipse-paho-mqtt-c::paho-mqtt3as, maybe it's missing this linking somehow? All the other parts of the cpp-library are able to be linked correctly.

If you add target_link_libraries(Test MQTTClient) in your first CMakeLists.txt where you define MQTTClient does it work? If yes, then the issue will be in your MQTTClientConfig.cmake

Test is built in a separate directory and not part of the MQTTClient project so it cannot be accessed via that cmake-file. My MQTTClientConfig.cmake.in looks like this:
@PACKAGE_INIT@

find_package(PahoMqttCpp REQUIRED)
find_package(nlohmann_json REQUIRED)

check_required_components(WaraPSClient)


Yeah I got it, but supposing you could move it to the same directory, I guess then it would work.

"Undefined reference" in a shared library means that the library itself is broken. Normally, you shouldn't be able to produce such library: you would get the same "undefined refererence" error when build your project (MQTTClient). When install a shared library, CMake strips RPATH settings. Probably, because of that your installed library becomes linked with libraries at locations, different from the ones for the library in the build tree. You could compare path of libraries in output of ldd <build-dir>/libMQTTClient.so and in output of ldd /usr/local/lib/libMQTTClient.so.

I managed to fix the issue after some time, the problem was not CMake-related but stemmed from a faulty apt download. After reinstalling the mqtt library from scratch I managed to compile everything just fine.
